# Find the given side of the following diagram

Tags: geometry

[image]

In Fig. $9.15$, $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, $AE \perp DC $ and $CF \perp AD$. If $AB=16$ $cm$, $AE=8$ $cm$ and $CF=10$ $cm$. Find $AD$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the area of the parallelogram can be represented both as
$$AE\times AB$$
and as
$$CF\times AD.$$

Hence, we have
$$AE\times AB=CF\times AD\Rightarrow 8\times 16=10\times AD\Rightarrow AD=\frac{8\times 16}{10}=\frac{64}{5}.$$